# how to search multiple value against multiple field in solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr-schema

How to search multiple value against multiple field in solr ?

My scenario :

Currently in schema.xml, i am using `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>` and

```
<copyField source="COL1" dest="defaultsearch"/>
<copyField source="COL2" dest="defaultsearch"/>
```

and

```
<fieldType name="text_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />      
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and

```
<defaultSearchField>defaultsearch</defaultSearchField>
```

Example:

My search query is like **q=Good Boy**.

I have to fetch the records like both **Good** and **Boy** should present in either COL1 or COL2.

But for me it gives the result as expected with additional results like **Good** present in COL1 and **Boy** present in COL2  or **Good** present in COL2 and **Boy** present in COL1.

Please suggest me how to find the results with both **Good** and **Boy** should present in either COL1 or COL2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't get your point. Can u please explain with example.

Comment: Could you please provide your current query and tell us what it does and what you think it should do!?

Comment: Sorry.. Contents updated as with additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you require exact match on COL1 and COL2, then you can execute the following (assuming COL1 and COL2 are strings) :-

```
q=(COL1:"Good Boy" OR COL2:"Good Boy")
```

If you do not require exact match and the phrase should contain both "Good" and "Boy" in any order, then try the following (untested) :-

```
q=(COL1:*Good Boy* OR COL2: *Good Boy*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max. For q=(COL1:*Good Boy* OR COL2: *Good Boy*) , it wont give the expected result. For that what i have done is **q=((COL1:*Good* AND COL1:*Boy*) OR (COL2:*Good* AND COL2:*Boy*))**